# Laravel 8.39.0 - PHP 7.4.18: When naming my class, I get the error "Unexpected 'match'. Expected 'Name'." but renaming my class resolves it

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am really banging my head against the wall at this point as the error seems to have cropped up quite randomly, and none of my coworkers are experiencing this error.

In one of our model files we have the following (names partially modified for data protection reasons):

`Match.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use App\Cat;
use App\Clothing;
use App\Events\CatMatched;
use App\Events\ClothingMatched;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use stdClass;

class Match extends Model
{
    const TYPE_THING      = 'thing';
```

I am getting a very strange error from `intelephense` and I don't believe it's just intelephense misbehaving since I actually can't run my application properly. All of my requests return 500 with no response. Additionally, there are a bunch of errors in the `Match.php` file itself, such as `Unexpected 'const'.` for the line where `TYPE_THING` is defined.

Now, if I change the class name of `Match` to be `Match2` and update all other instances accordingly in my code, the errors go away and I am able to run my application normally.

What in the world could be going on here?

Perhaps worth noting

- I am running Laravel using the pre-packaged [Vagrant Box](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead)
- Not a single one of my other models is having this problem, it just this one.
- I can successfully instantiate an instance of the `Match` class in an `php artisan tinker` session

Comment: In PHP 8, `match()` is a function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php. Consider a different name for your Model. (I see your PHP version is 7.4, but I can recreate this issue on PHP 7.x as well)

Comment: *"I can successfully instantiate an instance of the Match class in an `php artisan tinker` session"* - Partially true; `$m = new App\Models\Match()` and `App\Models\Match::first()` are fine, but `Match::first()` is unhappy: "PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" ("T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" meaning `::`)

Comment: probably because App\Models\Match() is namespaced Match::first isn't -> run php Match::first() in a terminal window mac, *nix - don't know windows you get php Match::first()
function>

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php  "You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. "

Comment: @TimLewis interesting, we probably should rename the model if it's going to become a reversed word in PHP 8. You mentioned you were able to recreate this issue in PHP 7.x - was there anything specific about your environment that allowed you to do this? My coworkers are running PHP 7.4 (the same as mine) and are not experiencing this problem.

Comment: Yeah, renaming is definitely a good idea, although it goes against Laravel naming convention if you're recording something like a tournament (Games, Sets, Matches, etc). And nope, nothing special about my set-up, Laravel 8.40, PHP 7.3, VSCode with Inteliphense 1.7.1

Comment: So I checked with them and one of them is running 7.4.5. It's strange to me that it's happening for you with an older PHP version (7.3), but they're not experiencing it with 7.4.5. Unfortunately `Match` really is the best name for the model but I suppose we'll have to think up something else.

Comment: Hmm, very strange... Different IDEs/no Inteliphense installed maybe? Hard to say... And I sympathize with the naming collision. You _might_ be able to get away with it if it's properly namespaced, but I wouldn't recommend actively trying to go against PHP-core in this instance. Best of luck with everything though :)